# How to exclude all the elements except than one within a for loop?

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop, cycle

I set a dynamic Ajax call to compare the string typed in the text field (which is the name of a city) and the value of the sub-key "type" in a JSON array.

I'm cycling the elements of such array to check the values of the key "type".
I want to include in the search results both the elements whose key "type" has the value equal to "city" and those whose key "type" has the value equal to "hamlet".

For there are some cities which are indexed with both of them (i.e.: some elements of the JSON array have the value of "type" equal to "city" and others have the value of "type" equal to "hamlet"), I want to avoid those cities to be indexed more than once/to be duplicated.

To be more precise, the ajax call is the following:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=" + encodeURIComponent($("#inlineFormInputCitta").val()) + "&format=geocodejson",
  dataType: "json",

  success: function(data) {
    var check = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++) {
      let typeCity = data.features[i].properties.geocoding.type;
      if (typeCity === "city") {
        let nameCity = data.features[i].properties.geocoding.name;
        for (let i = 0; i < francigena.tappe.length; i++) {
          let tappa = francigena.tappe[i];
          let city = francigena.tappe[i].city;
          let fs = francigena.tappe[i].fs;

          if (city === nameCity && fs === "true") {
            check = true;
            $('#tabellaEconteuti').show();

          } else if (city === nameCity) {
            check = true;
            console.log("JSON file has been activated");
            $('#tabellaEconteuti').show();

            $("#tbody").append("<tr><td>" + tappa.name + "</td><td>" + tappa.state + "</td><td>" + tappa.region + "</td><td>" + tappa.city + "</td></tr>");
            $("#tabella").show();
          }
        };
      };
    }


    if (
      !check
    ) {
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
  },
}
```

What I'm doing here is a dynamic call to associate the string typed in the input form to the one included on the url in the API call:

```
url: "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=" + encodeURIComponent($("#inlineFormInputCitta").val()) + "&format=geocodejson",
```

Then I wrote `if (typeCity === "city") { //some function here}`

I want to write the same function when the following condition is fulfilled:

```
if (typeCity === "hamlet")
```

But the problem is the following:

[image]

i.e. the city "Lucca has both the

```
"type": "city",
```

and the

```
"type": "hamlet",
```

therefore, for the `for loop` cycles all the elements in the array, the city Lucca is displayed twice in the search results in my webpage: the first one because "type" is equal to "city"; the second one because "type" is equal to "hamlet".

I want to write two `for loop`functions, the first one to include the results which come from `typeCity : "hamlet"`; the second one to include the results which include "type": "city" but not `"typeCity" : "hamlet"`. Therefore cities which have both are displayed once only.

How may I exclude all the elements except than one in a `for loop` function? Or are there any other methods to achieve the goal?

- - - -E D I T - - - - ->

I'm trying to solve the problem by using the Set() method:

```
success: function(data) {
    var check = false;
    var cityList = new Set()
    for (let i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++) {
        let typeCity = data.features[i].properties.geocoding.type;
        if (typeCity === "hamlet") {
            let nameCity = data.features[i].properties.geocoding.name;
            for (let i = 0; i < francigena.tappe.length; i++) {
                let tappa = francigena.tappe[i];
                let city = francigena.tappe[i].city;
                let fs = francigena.tappe[i].fs;
                if (city === nameCity && fs === "true") {
                    check = true;
                    console.log(" 'fs' === 'true' has been activated");
                    $('#tabellaEconteuti').show();

                    $("#tabella").show();

                } else if (city === nameCity) {
                    check = true;
                    console.log("JSON file has been activated");
                    $('#tabellaEconteuti').show();

                }
                if (cityList.has(city)) {
                    continue
                }
                cityList.add(city);
                if (typeCity === "city") {
                    let tappa = francigena.tappe[i];
                    let city = francigena.tappe[i].city;
                    let fs = francigena.tappe[i].fs;
                    if (city === nameCity && fs === "true") {
                        check = true;
                        console.log(" 'fs' === 'true' has been activated");
                        $('#tabellaEconteuti').show();

                        $('#TrenitaliaButton').on('click', showTrenitaliaInfo);

                    } else if (city === nameCity) {
                        check = true;
                        console.log("JSON file has been activated");
                        $('#tabellaEconteuti').show();
                    }
                }
            }
        } {
            {
                let nameCity = data.features[i].properties.geocoding.name;
                for (let i = 0; i < francigena.tappe.length; i++) {
                    let tappa = francigena.tappe[i];
                    let city = francigena.tappe[i].city;
                    let fs = francigena.tappe[i].fs;
                    if (city === nameCity && fs === "true") {
                        check = true;
                        console.log(" 'fs' === 'true' has been activated");
                        $('#tabellaEconteuti').show();


                    } else if (city === nameCity) {
                        check = true;
                        console.log("JSON file has been activated");

                        $('#tabellaEconteuti').show();

                    }
                };
            }
        };
    }
    if (
        !check
    ) {
        $('#tabellaEconteuti').hide();
    }
},
```

It doesn't work because the city is displayed eight times more than expected.
How should I use the `Set()` method instead?

- - -E D I T - - - -

I suppose I should change the method: instead than using the `var cityList = new Set()` I want to do the following:

1) I check whether or not the value of "type" is "city"; if I found it may set a variable A to say that I found it.

2) Next, I write a second `for loop` to check whether or not the value of "type" is "hamlet".

I guess it may be the right way to follow because it seems to be an easier way to accomplish the task.
How may I set such a variable A?

Comment: In your first loop keep an array of all the names who pass the other tests.
In second loop check if the current name is already in the array of names. This would be the solution if you don't want duplicates with the same name. Did I understand that correctly?

Comment: @Wimanicesir should I create a new var which is an array?

Comment: "*the city Lucca is displayed twice*" - no. Those are simply two distinct cities, and of course you'd want to display both of them?

Comment: The example displayed in the image shows two different cities. Probably the API is already returning unique cities, you just misunderstood the result.

Comment: @Wimanicesir I edited my Question (see the last edit), is what you did mean?

Answer (score 0):

Set would be a suitable choice here than Array. For each city check it already present in cityList. If present continue to next city, otherwise add to cityList and continue with the code.

Do the same check for the other array.

```
var check = false; 
var cityList = new Set()
for (let i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++) {
    let typeCity = data.features[i].properties.geocoding.type;
    if (typeCity === "city") {
        let nameCity = data.features[i].properties.geocoding.name;
        for (let i = 0; i < francigena.tappe.length; i++) {
            let tappa = francigena.tappe[i];
            let city = francigena.tappe[i].city;
            let fs = francigena.tappe[i].fs;

            if (cityList.has(city)) {
                continue;
            }
            cityList.add(city);

            if (city === nameCity && fs === "true") {
                check = true;                                       
                $('#tabellaEconteuti').show(); 

            } else if (city === nameCity) {
                check = true;
                console.log("JSON file has been activated");                                       
                $('#tabellaEconteuti').show();

                $("#tbody").append("<tr><td>" + tappa.name + "</td><td>" + tappa.state + "</td><td>" + tappa.region + "</td><td>" + tappa.city + "</td></tr>");    
                $("#tabella").show();                                        
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by setting a boolean variable `locationFound` and the `break` statement to jump out of the loop.

Firstly, I set the variable as false by default, outside and before the `for loop` cycle.
Secondly, I run the for loop cycle and I set the variable as true inside of it. Some actions are performed and then I set a `break` statement to jump out for the loop once the value is found.

Then I set the variable as false as a condition in the `if statement` outside the `for loop`. Some actions are performed and then I set another `break` statement to jump out for the loop once the value is found.
It works: all the results are shown as expected and without duplicates:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=" + encodeURIComponent($("#inlineFormInputCitta").val()) + "&format=geocodejson",
        dataType: "json",            

        success: function (data) {                

            for (let i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++) {

                var locationFound = false; //I set the boolean variable as false by default
                let typeCity = data.features[i].properties.geocoding.type;

                if (typeCity === "city") {
                    locationFound = true;  //here the boolean variable is true and an action is performed

                    break;    // I jump out of the loop
                    }

                else if (locationFound === false) {
                    if (typeCity === "hamlet") {
                        var locationFound = true; //the boolean variable becomes true and the actions below are performed
                        //show the table
                        break;   //I jump out of the loop                         
                    }
                }
```